# Apple apns push notification i iOS 6

Tags: ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i'm trying to set push notifications for my new app and i have heard that in ios 6 device token changes  each time the app is launched !

Is it true ?

Can someone tell me what i've changed to Apns in iOS 6 ?

Thanks a lot for any help. (i've google it do not worry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true.
Device Token rarely changes (it usually only changes if you change your iOS version or restore your device from a backup).
In fact, all the applications on the same device have the same device token.
And these things haven't changed in iOS6.

Comment: thank you very much ! It is just the method to get the device that changes is that true ?

Comment: @user2206906 Not that I'm aware of. What makes you think it changed?

Comment: Can anyone tell what is the alternative for register device token? I am getting a warning in my project of "Register Device Token is deprecated as in libuairship1.3.0. Please help me if anyone knows this.

Comment: @ManthanPatel Did question has nothing to do with Urban Airship. Perhaps you should post a new question (or search for an existing question about Urban Airship).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless if the device token changes or not, it's best to re-register each time the app is launched to handle the possibility of a change (which CAN happen in some circumstances).

In your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you should use this code to avoid any problems that may arise due to the device token changing:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
}
```